# Calculate mean of groups for a binary (0/1) database

Tags: r, dplyr, binary, mean, logistic-regression

I have a database containing the presence (1) or absence (0) of cells in different growth stages (enlarging, thickening and maturing) for different trees during many years. I collected data every certain days of the year (DOY; January 1 would be DOY 1, January 2 would be DOY 2, etc.). Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame("Year" = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012,
                            2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013,
                            2013, 2013),
                 "Tree" = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 41, 41,
                            41, 41, 41),
                 "DOY" = c(65, 97, 125, 177, 214, 65, 97, 125, 177, 214,
                           61, 99, 118, 166, 221),
                 "Enlarging" = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                 "Thickening" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 "Maturing" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))

print(df)
 Year Tree DOY Enlarging Thickening Maturing
1  2012   15  65         0          0        0
2  2012   15  97         0          0        0
3  2012   15 125         1          1        1
4  2012   15 177         0          1        1
5  2012   15 214         0          0        0
6  2012   22  65         0          0        0
7  2012   22  97         1          0        0
8  2012   22 125         1          1        1
9  2012   22 177         1          1        1
10 2012   22 214         0          0        0
11 2013   41  61         0          0        0
12 2013   41  99         1          0        1
13 2013   41 118         1          1        1
14 2013   41 166         1          1        1
15 2013   41 221         0          0        0
```

I just want to calculate the yearly `mean` of all trees for every DOY but I'm not sure how to write the syntax. I tried something like this, but obviously I ended up calculating the arithmetic mean instead of obtaining a binary mean:

```
df_mean <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, DOY) %>%
  summarise(Enlarging_mean = mean(Enlarging),
            Thickening_mean = mean(Thickening), 
            Mature_mean = mean(Maturing))
```

Also tried this but ended up getting decimals again.

```
df_mean <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, DOY) %>%
  summarise(Enlarging_mean = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Enlarging))),
            Thickening_mean = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Thickening))), 
            Mature_mean = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Maturing))))
```

Does anyone know how to apply the `mean` function properly in this example? Thank you so much.

Comment: I've never heard of a binary mean - can you give any details on how it's calculated?

Comment: There are statistical models, like logistic regression, where it is common to express a binary possibility in decimal terms, related to the probability of an event. The decimal answers your are getting sound like a reasonable outcome here, and it's not obvious to me what the alternative would be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to round to 0 digits.

To do this, you could add a `mutate()` + `across()` + `round()` to your code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(DOY, Year) %>% 
  summarise(Enlarging_mean = mean(Enlarging),
            Thickening_mean = mean(Thickening), 
            Mature_mean = mean(Maturing)) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(),
                ~ round(.x, digits = 0)))

# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   DOY [10]
     DOY  Year Enlarging_mean Thickening_mean Mature_mean
   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl>
 1    61  2013              0               0           0
 2    65  2012              0               0           0
 3    97  2012              0               0           0
 4    99  2013              1               0           1
 5   118  2013              1               1           1
 6   125  2012              1               1           1
 7   166  2013              1               1           1
 8   177  2012              0               1           1
 9   214  2012              0               0           0
10   221  2013              0               0           0
```